# Has VLC permanently stopped supporting Twitch?

Tags: vlc-media-player, twitch

I used to be able to play Twitch streams in VLC. A few months ago, this started breaking. Then they updated VLC and since then (I have the latest version), it just does *nothing* when you enter a Twitch stream URL -- no stream and no error message. Literally nothing happens.

I don't know how to interpret this, but it's a nightmare now that I'm forced to use a browser. It takes like 10-15 seconds to open each stream now compared to a split second with VLC.